# ado.net does not return data in SQL Builtin function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

I have following method, but it does not fill datatable.

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1))
{
    conn.Open();
   string query = "SELECT distinct left(RTRIM(PostalCode), 2),EntityID FROM  Gen_Addresses";
    dt = new DataTable();
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query ,conn);

    ad.Fill(dt);
    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns["PostalCode"].ColumnName;
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = dt.Columns["EntityID"].ColumnName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1))
            {
                conn.Open();
               string query = "SELECT distinct left(RTRIM(PostalCode), 2),EntityID FROM  Gen_Addresses";
               SqlCommand cmd=null;
                cmd=new SqlCommand(query ,conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
                ad.SelectCommand=cmd;
                ad.Fill(dt);
                checkedListBox1.DisplayMember =     dt.Columns["PostalCode"].ColumnName;
                checkedListBox1.ValueMember = dt.Columns["EntityID"].ColumnName;


            }
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a column alias in the query in order to reference the expression by name instead of ordinal:

```
string query = "SELECT distinct left(RTRIM(PostalCode), 2) AS PostalCode,EntityID FROM  Gen_Addresses";
```